# Is x%a a Fortran 90 array section?

Tags: fortran, fortran90

With a user defined type such as `foo`:

```
type, public :: foo
  integer :: a(4)
end type foo
```

and a variable `x` of that type:

```
type(foo) :: x
```

is `x%a` an *array section*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

x%a(:) is an array section, x%a refers to the entire array.